# Sending syslog-ng events through a proxy server

Tags: proxy, syslog-ng

Most applications have a specific method for using a proxy, what's the proper way to send syslog data through a proxy in syslog-ng?

Comment: What kind of proxy do you want to use? Do you mean a syslog relay between the client and the logserver, or something else?

Comment: What do you want exactly using Syslog-ng, can you please share your requirement ?